# Chart works only on reload

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to display data on a chart (using chart.js).

To do this, I'm using nuxt, a back-end api and mongodb.

I can get the data from the db, but the chart appear only on reload (picture)

[image: chart on reload]

This is my script code of my component :

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bgColor: "#81894e",
      beginZero: true,
      borderColor: "#FF7F02 ",
      btn: [
        { label: "This year", value: "weight" }
      ],
      data: {
        weight: [],
      },
      dataLabel: "poids",
      labels: {
        month: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jui"]
      },
      radio: "weight",
      labelRadio: "month"
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/getUserWeight');
  },
 methods: {
    user() {
      let data = this.$store.getters['user/getWeight'];
      if (this.data.weight.length == 0) {
        this.data.weight =  String(data).split(",").map(Number);
      }
    }
  }
```

I dont know where is my mistake

Comment: Chart.js works only on client-side, not on server-side. So have you init your component with the  chart on a "mounted()" method or inside a nuxt "<client-only>" element ? (see https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/)

Comment: my chartLine component, is imported in my graph Component.
And my graph Component is imported himslef in my index.vue page...

In my chartLine component, i have a mounted() to dispatch an action from my store...
In my Graph component, there is a <no-ssr> element (your <client-only> element)

hope it's help you